# Visual C++ express 2010 The procedure entry point ??1task_group_context@tbb@@QAE@XZ could not be located in the dynamic link library tbb.dll

Tags: c++, procedure, tbb

Can someone help me out with this error?

I tried researching on the internet and tried the different methods to resolve the problem (eg: uninstalling other versions of visual c++, adding codes, etc), but none of them seem to work :(

What I have done:

```
under c/c++-->general-->additional include directories-->C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include;C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include\opencv2;C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include\opencv;C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\data\haarcascades

under linker-->general-->additional library directories-->C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x86\vc9\lib;C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\data\haarcascades;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

under linker-->input-->additional dependencies--> added opencv_core230.lib;opencv_highgui230.lib;opencv_objdetect230.lib

under debugging-->command arguments -->added --cascade="C:/Program Files/OpenCV/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"testimg.jpg
```

The code:

```
#include <cv.h> 
#include <highgui.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Create memory for calculations
static CvMemStorage* storage = 0;

// Create a new Haar classifier
static CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = 0;

// Function prototype for detecting and drawing an object from an image
void detect_and_draw( IplImage* image );

// Create a string that contains the cascade name
const char* cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
/*    "haarcascade_profileface.xml";*/

// Main function, defines the entry point for the program.
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    // Structure for getting video from camera or avi
    CvCapture* capture = 0;

    // Images to capture the frame from video or camera or from file
    IplImage *frame, *frame_copy = 0;
    /*  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "testimg.jpg" ); 
    cvNamedWindow( "MyJPG", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); 
    cvShowImage("MyJPG", img); 
    cvWaitKey(0); 
    cvReleaseImage( &img ); 
    cvDestroyWindow( "MyJPG" ); 
    */
    // Used for calculations
    int optlen = strlen("--cascade=");

    // Input file name for avi or image file.
    const char* input_name;

    // Check for the correct usage of the command line
    if( argc > 1 && strncmp( argv[1], "--cascade=", optlen ) == 0 )
    {
        cascade_name = argv[1] + optlen;
        input_name = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf( stderr,
        "Usage: facedetect --cascade=\"<cascade_path>\" [filename|camera_index]\n" );
        return -1;
        /*input_name = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : 0;*/
    }

    // Load the HaarClassifierCascade
    cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( cascade_name, 0, 0, 0 );

    // Check whether the cascade has loaded successfully. Else report and error and quit
    if( !cascade )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    // Allocate the memory storage
    storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    // Find whether to detect the object from file or from camera.
    if( !input_name || (isdigit(input_name[0]) && input_name[1] == '\0') )
        capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( !input_name ? 0 : input_name[0] - '0' );
    else
        capture = cvCaptureFromAVI( input_name ); 

    // Create a new named window with title: result
    cvNamedWindow( "result", 1 );

    // Find if the capture is loaded successfully or not.

    // If loaded succesfully, then:
    if( capture )
    {
        // Capture from the camera.
        for(;;)
        {
            // Capture the frame and load it in IplImage
            if( !cvGrabFrame( capture ))
                break;
            frame = cvRetrieveFrame( capture );

            // If the frame does not exist, quit the loop
            if( !frame )
                break;

            // Allocate framecopy as the same size of the frame
            if( !frame_copy )
                frame_copy = cvCreateImage( cvSize(frame->width,frame->height),
                                            IPL_DEPTH_8U, frame->nChannels );

            // Check the origin of image. If top left, copy the image frame to frame_copy. 
            if( frame->origin == IPL_ORIGIN_TL )
                cvCopy( frame, frame_copy, 0 );
            // Else flip and copy the image
            else
                cvFlip( frame, frame_copy, 0 );

            // Call the function to detect and draw the face
            detect_and_draw( frame_copy );

            // Wait for a while before proceeding to the next frame
            if( cvWaitKey( 10 ) >= 0 )
                break;
        }

        // Release the images, and capture memory
        cvReleaseImage( &frame_copy );
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    }

    // If the capture is not loaded succesfully, then:
    else
    {
        // Assume the image to be lena.jpg, or the input_name specified
        const char* filename = input_name ? input_name : (char*)"testimg.jpg";

        // Load the image from that filename
        IplImage* image = cvLoadImage( filename, 1 );

        // If Image is loaded succesfully, then:
        if( image )
        {
            // Detect and draw the face
            detect_and_draw( image );

            // Wait for user input
            cvWaitKey(0);

            // Release the image memory
            cvReleaseImage( &image );
        }
        else
        {
            /* assume it is a text file containing the
               list of the image filenames to be processed - one per line */
            FILE* f = fopen( filename, "rt" );
            if( f )
            {
                char buf[1000+1];

                // Get the line from the file
                while( fgets( buf, 1000, f ) )
                {

                    // Remove the spaces if any, and clean up the name
                    int len = (int)strlen(buf);
                    while( len > 0 && isspace(buf[len-1]) )
                        len--;
                    buf[len] = '\0';

                    // Load the image from the filename present in the buffer
                    image = cvLoadImage( buf, 1 );

                    // If the image was loaded succesfully, then:
                    if( image )
                    {
                        // Detect and draw the face from the image
                        detect_and_draw( image );

                        // Wait for the user input, and release the memory
                        cvWaitKey(0);
                        cvReleaseImage( &image );
                    }
                }
                // Close the file
                fclose(f);
            }
        }    
    }

    // Destroy the window previously created with filename: "result"
    cvDestroyWindow("result");

    // return 0 to indicate successfull execution of the program
    return 0;
}

// Function to detect and draw any faces that is present in an image
void detect_and_draw( IplImage* img )
{
    int scale = 1;

    // Create a new image based on the input image
    IplImage* temp = cvCreateImage( cvSize(img->width/scale,img->height/scale), 8, 3 );

    // Create two points to represent the face locations
    CvPoint pt1, pt2;
    int i;

    // Clear the memory storage which was used before
    cvClearMemStorage( storage );

    // Find whether the cascade is loaded, to find the faces. If yes, then:
    if( cascade )
    {    
        // There can be more than one face in an image. So create a growable sequence of faces.
        // Detect the objects and store them in the sequence
        CvSeq* faces = cvHaarDetectObjects( img, cascade, storage,
                                            1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                            cvSize(40, 40) );

        // Loop the number of faces found.
        for( i = 0; i < (faces ? faces->total : 0); i++ )
        {
            // Create a new rectangle for drawing the face
            CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );

            // Find the dimensions of the face,and scale it if necessary
            pt1.x = r->x*scale;
            pt2.x = (r->x+r->width)*scale;
            pt1.y = r->y*scale;
            pt2.y = (r->y+r->height)*scale;

            // Draw the rectangle in the input image
            cvRectangle( img, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 3, 8, 0 );
        }
    }

    // Show the image in the window named "result"
    cvShowImage( "result", img );

    // Release the temp image created.
    cvReleaseImage( &temp );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says, that a certain symbol could not be found in an external library, tbb.dll. The library (the dll) itself seems to be found.

The library is [Threading building blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) and your error message hints to a mismatch between header and the used dll, for example because of multiple versions installed etc. You should find out, if the correct dll is used at runtime (check the modules window in VS, or use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for that).
To point the runtime application to the correct path of tbb.dll, you might put the directory in your PATH environment variable, or put the tbb.dll side by side to the Executable.